# Versioning Ruby gems in a git repository

Tags: ruby, git, rubygems

What are best practices for storing your gems in one git repository? Should they be kept in one repository? Should each gem be versioned on its own? I'm mostly concerned with gems that are shared on a per project basis - even though that defeats the purpose of a gem, which can be reused and shared in other projects. I wanted an easy way to keep all of my gems versioned, preferably without having to worry about 50 git repos.. and push them to a gem server whenever they're ready to be pushed.

Comment: And what are you trying to do?  Doesn't bundler or rvm gemsets (or both) solve your problem?  Putting gems in git seems a bit extreme.

Comment: I should probably clarify that I want the gems code base versioned. I don't think being able to see history and running source control on gems is extreme by any means. It's just another piece of software that can take advantage of version control like any other software.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Maarons that bundler and/or rvm gemsets are best practice, but if you want to keep your gem code versioned as part of your applications repo, then I think the solution you're looking for is to vendor your gems and then add them as submodules to your application's git repo.

You can vendor your current gems by running the rake task: `rake gems:build`

Any new gems you want to install can be installed as a plugin by running `ruby script/plugin install your_plugin` . That should clone the git repo of the plugin you're interested in. See appropriate plugin docs for more options (like to grab a specific release).